# Unable to update package using pacman due to gnupg corruption

Tags: arch-linux, gnupg

I managed to hose my system and now update to run pacman to update.  When a package is attempted to update the system reports `is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)`

It seems the gnupg program is missing now.  When trying to execute `gpg` the following message is reported

`gpg: symbol lookup error: gpg: undefined symbol: gpgrt_access, version GPG_ERROR_1.0`

When I try to install gnupg using `sudo pacman -S gnupg` the following is reported

```
[Arch ~]$ sudo pacman -S gnupg
warning: gnupg-2.2.27-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) gnupg-2.2.27-1

Total Download Size:   2.41 MiB
Total Installed Size:  9.88 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
 gnupg-2.2.27-1-x86_64                                                        2.4 MiB  13.4 MiB/s 00:00 [##############################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                          [##############################################################] 100%
warning: Public keyring not found; have you run 'pacman-key --init'?
error: GPGME error: Invalid crypto engine
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                        [##############################################################] 100%
warning: Public keyring not found; have you run 'pacman-key --init'?
error: GPGME error: Invalid crypto engine
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/gnupg-2.2.27-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

I changed the SigLevel in /etc/pacman.conf to `TrustAll`, but still see the same issue.  How can I get gnupg installed correctly and resolve the `corrupted package (PGP signature)` error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer to my issue via an [Arch BBS posting](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263716)

By following these steps

> I disabled the check in the file /etc/pacman.conf and restored the
> system, I changed SigLevel = Never
>
> Then executed: pacman -Scc pacman -Syu
>
> Then reinstalled gpg packet, Rebooted the system... And executed: sudo
> pacman-key --init && sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux && sudo
> pacman-key --refresh-keys
>
> Then I enabled checking keys and rebooted the system.

Once I followed these steps I was able to install all the updates and login to the desktop environment.